# How is login.ubuntu.com implemented?

Tags: login, ubuntu-one, launchpad

I'd like to build a single sign-on system similar to [login.ubuntu.com](https://login.ubuntu.com).

Is there any source code available? If not, do you know on which technologies this has been built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

login.ubuntu.com is an OpenID provider. It is a Free Software project released under the terms of the GNU Affero GPL v3. You can find it on Launchpad in the [canonical-identity-provider project](https://launchpad.net/canonical-identity-provider).

Answer (score -1):

It would use PHP probably and then save your data into a SQL database. Pretty much you enter the data into the HTML form which is then sent to the server. The server analyses the data to see if it's legitimate and then performs an action based upon it. If you are logging in, the server will likely sent session data and cookies to and from the server-client in order to establish a secure login. If you are registering, the server would create a new table into its SQL database with your username on the left and other data in the cells to the right.